# Getting 'ReferenceError: describe is not defined' error when going to start the application

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, nestjs, inversifyjs

I'm going to test typescript(inversify) code using jest. Below mentioned the code that use to test a controller method.

```
describe('Test UserController',() =>{

    let userService : UserServiceImpl = new UserServiceImpl();
    let userController : UserController = new UserController(userService);
    let req, res, next;

    beforeEach(() => {
        req = httpMocks.createRequest();
        res = httpMocks.createResponse();
        next = jest.fn();

        req.authorization = 'eyJIjoxNjE0NTc2Mzc3LCJleHAiOjE2NDYxMTIzNzd9';

        jest.mock("../../service/user-service-impl");
    });   
    
    afterEach(() =>{
        jest.resetAllMocks();
    });

    it('getUser method should work properly',async() => {
        const userResponseStub : UserResponse = new UserResponse();
        userResponseStub.username = 'username';
        userResponseStub.email = 'email@test.com';
        
        jest.spyOn(userService, "getUser").mockResolvedValue(userResponseStub);
        const response = await userController.getUser(1);
        expect(response).toBe(userResponseStub);  
    });
});
```

Below mentioned the configurations related to jest in `package.json` file

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testResultsProcessor": "jest-sonar-reporter",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,tsx,ts}",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/vendor/**"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "json"
    ],
    "coverageReporters": [
      "lcov",
      "text"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": [
      "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(ts?|tsx?)$"
    ]
  },
  "jestSonar": {
    "sonar56x": true
  }
```

Test case is run without any issue. But I'm going to run the application using `npm start` , getting below error.

```
describe('Test UserController',() =>{
^
ReferenceError: describe is not defined
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Any help or workarounds are really appriciated.

Comment: add these spec files to the `exclude` array in your `tsconfig.json` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#examples

Comment: @MicaelLevi Thanks for the reply. I added below lines to tsconfig.json file. But the error is same.

 "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.test.ts"]

Comment: what if you add `'jest'` to your `tsconfig.json` `types` array?  I didn't understand why typescript is type checking these spec files when you run `npm start`

Comment: @MicaelLevi Below is my tsconfig.json file.

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}

Comment: add the entry `"types": ["jest", "node"]` to `compilerOptions` and do `npm start`. Show your `start` npm-script

Comment: @MicaelLevi I add "types": ["jest", "node"]  to compilerOptions. But it getting same error. Below I mentioned the scripts object in package.json.

"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run start-env-dev",
    "start-env-dev": "ts-node src/user-api --NODE_ENV=dev",
    "start:dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn src/user-api --NODE_ENV=dev",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage --coverageDirectory=coverage",
  }

Answer (score 0):

I've also encoutered "describe is not defined" error while running my app,
and while the issue might be something else - I'll share what was the solution here,  because maybe someone else will come to this page searching for answer.

So - in my case the problem was that, in my test file (lets say `example.test.tsx`)
I've created a mock (lets say `const EXAMPLE_MOCK = {name: 'Bob'}`),
and I've used this mock in a component (`<div>My name is {EXAMPLE_MOCK.name}</div>`).

I guess the problem was that, by default, when your application is starting
the code in `(...)test(...)` files is not built,
but because I've imported something from that file - it had to be built,
and compiler found out that there's some unknown function (`describe`) there.

When you normally run tests you run it with test-specific script,
which knows what `describe` is, so then it's not an issue.